# How do you use a macro from inside its own crate?

Tags: rust

I'm sure this is trivial to do, but I can't seem to make it work.

I've looked at http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/advanced-macros.html#scoping-and-macro-import/export, and I appreciate, that in general, the way to use macros is to define them using:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! background(($token:expr) => (($token >> (32 + 8)) & $crate::graphics::mask::Color));
```

...and then import them into another context that uses them using:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate terminal;
...
```

However, I what I want to do is use the macros from within the crate where they are defined.

If my file structure is:

```
- lib.rs
- macros.rs
- foo
- foo/mod.rs
- foo/junk.rs
```

How do I use the macros in macros.rs from junk.rs?

I've tried various combinations of `#[macro_use] mod macros`, etc. with no luck. The documentation suggests that if a macro is defined in some scope, then it is available in all child modules... does that mean I have to define my macros in lib.rs?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to mark your macro with `#[macro_export]` and then mark the module with `#[macro_use]`:

```
#[macro_use]
mod macros {
    #[macro_export]
    macro_rules! my_macro(() => (42));
}

pub mod foo {
    pub mod junk {
        pub fn usage() -> u8 {
            my_macro!()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", foo::junk::usage());
}
```

Technically, you only need to use `#[macro_export]` if you want the macro to be available to users of your crate.

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d871cd1d4fb7a488f62073ee144bd43f&version=stable&mode=debug))

Comment: That works inline, but when I try it using files, it doesn't seem to; have a look at this trivial example https://github.com/shadowmint/rust-starter; it errors with "src/module1/blah.rs:2:15: 2:18 error: macro undefined: 'fmt!'", but https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shadowmint/rust-starter/master/src/lib.rs does exactly what you've said.

Comment: There's no `mod module1;` in the code you link, maybe the error is coming from something else?

Comment: (See also: http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/advanced-macros.html#scoping-and-macro-import/export.)

Comment: @huon-dbaupp ah, right you are, it needed to be in main.rs

Comment: Might it be worth noting that `mod macros {}` must appear before other `mod` declarations depending on the macros?

Answer (score 74):

The accepted answer is correct, but for anyone else who finds this question in the future, I'd like to add that the *order* in which modules are loaded is important.

For example, in this sequence:

```
pub mod terminal;
pub mod terminals;
pub mod graphics;

#[macro_use]
mod macros;
```

If terminal uses a macro from macros, it will *not* work; the `#[macro_use]` must occur above any other module that uses the macro:

```
#[macro_use]
mod macros;

pub mod terminal;
pub mod terminals;
pub mod graphics;
```

Comment: This was exactly my issue! I wish it was highlighted in the book.